# REST: What is a good Hypermedia and Resource Caching Strategy?

Tags: http, caching, rest, hateoas

If I have a RESTful service that has discoverable resources via an endpoint such as:

Request:

```
GET http://acme.org/someInfo
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: ...
Content-Type: application/vnd.acme+xml
Date: Fri, 16 Dec 2012 12:40:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 1 Mar 2012 11:45:00 GMT

<someInfo xmlns="http://schemas.acme.org/someInfo" xmlns:dap="http://schemas.acme.org/dap">
    <dap:link rel="http://relations.acme.org/someInfo" uri="htp://acme.org/someInfo/foo" />
    <dap:link rel="http://relations.acme.org/someInfo" uri="htp://acme.org/someInfo/bar" />
    <dap:link rel="http://relations.acme.org/someInfo" uri="htp://acme.org/someInfo/baz" />
</someInfo>
```

And then with this response, a client may then follow one of the hypermedia links:

Request:

```
GET http://acme.org/someInfo/foo
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: ...
Content-Type: application/vnd.acme+xml
Date: Fri, 16 Dec 2012 12:45:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Sep 2012 11:45:00 GMT

<fooInfo xmlns="http://schemas.acme.org/fooInfo">
...
</fooInfo>
```

The first response may change less frequently (ex: many months), and the second one may change slightly more frequently (ex: every month or so).  What is a good HTTP caching strategy for this sort of scenario; by date, client ETag comparison, something else?

**EDIT: If the data is stale in magnitudes of a day or so, that is fine.  Any more would probably be problematic.**

Answer (score 0):

This is a performance versus consistency issue that really can only be answered by the business.

For each resource you need to ask two questions:

1. If the resource changes and the users do not see that change for X
   hours, what is the business impact? Will reactors explode if the user does not see the temperature change?
2. How much does it cost to see
   a new version of that resource?  Are you on a 1Gbps local network,
   or accessing it from a mobile phone in Siberia?

Once you know how valuable it is to have that data up-to-date and how much it costs to get that data then you can decide on the best caching strategy.

Comment: That's a good point.  I've edited my original question to reflect the issue of staleness.